# How to cnvert the date freq data into a dataframe in python and how to draw the histogram for that converted dataframe using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So i have a data like the below when i use this code:

```
>>datefreq = textdata[['date','smstext']]  
>>date_freq = datefreq.groupby('date').agg(len)
>>date_freq
                smstext_freq
   date
   2015-02-03    1
   2015-02-04    1500
   2015-02-05    13526
   2015-02-03    54444
```

How can i convert this into a dataframe

expected output:

> date_freq

```
      date          smstext_freq
  0  2015-02-03      1
  1  2015-02-04      1500
  2  2015-02-05      13526
  3  2015-02-03      54444
```

please help me how to write the code for the above in python and please tell me how to draw the histogram for the converted data if you can

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `date_freq` is already a Pandas [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) object. However, the dates are set as the index; you would like the dates to appear as an ordinary column. There is a one-line solution to this: use the [`reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method.

```
>>> date_freq.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> print data_freq

        date  smstext_freq
0 2015-02-03             1
1 2015-02-04          1500
2 2015-02-05         13526
3 2015-02-06         54444
```

Now you also want a [histogram](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html#histograms). Call the Pandas [`plot()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) method on `date_freq['smstext_freq']`, and set `kind='hist'`. This will return a [`matplotlib.axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) object, which you can fine-tune however you want. Here, I've just added a title and an x-axis label.

```
>>> ax = date_freq['smstext_freq'].plot(kind='hist')
>>> ax.set_title('SMS Text Frequency per Day')
>>> ax.set_xlabel('SMS Text Frequency')
>>> plt.show()
```

Here is the resulting histogram. It should look more interesting with more data, as well as with any other tweaks you may want to make to the graph.
[image: SMS histogram]